# Get number of likes Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get the number of likes of a post with the help of [fb sdk for c#](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk).

Below is the code I'm trying

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(page_access_token);
var like = fb.Get(post_id+"/likes");
```

But, I'm getting the below text in reply:

> {"data":[] }

I'm using the sdk for other things like posting on page, etc and its working perfectly.

Just having trouble getting the no. of likes.

Am I making a wrong Get request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points where this could go wrong:

- The page access token has no permissions to view the post you are requesting
- The post itself has no likes

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes/

As in these docs, you need to add a `summary=true` parameter to the request:

```
var like = fb.Get(post_id+"/likes?summary=true");
```

Comment: I liked the post and then ran the code again. I'm getting
{"data":[{'id":"the_id_here","name":"the_name_of_page"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"after":"some_random_string","before":"some_random_string"}}}

Comment: Yes trying to get no. of likes for a post made on a page. Check my edit

Comment: OK, then there were no likes on this post. To get the number of likes, check the edit I made to my answer